# hapi-auth-cookie not setting cookie immediately after redirect with bell

Tags: cookies, oauth-2.0, hapi.js

I'm using Bell for Meetup OAuth, then persisting with hapi-auth-cookie.

Here are the relevant parts of code.

```
server.auth.strategy('session', 'cookie', {
    cookie: 'sessionid',
    password: '32_char_password',
    // redirectTo: '/login', //this causes a loop immediately after allowing access
    redirectTo: false,
    isSecure: false,
});

server.auth.strategy('meetupauth', 'bell', {
    provider: 'meetup',
    password: '32_char_password',
    isSecure: false,
    providerParams: {
        set_mobile: 'on'
    },
    clientId: 'client_id',
    clientSecret: 'client_secret',
});

server.route({
    method: ['GET'],
    path: '/login',
    config: {
        auth: 'meetupauth',
        handler: (request, reply) => {

            request.cookieAuth.set({
                sid: request.auth.credentials.profile
            });

            return reply.redirect('/user');
        }
    }
});

server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/user',
    config: {
        auth: 'session',
        handler: (request, reply) => reply('My Account'),
    }
});
```

The code works fine, except immediately after allowing access to Meetup. Once allowed access, the `/login` page redirects to `/user`.  Not redirecting back to the login page, I get a 401, and after I reload `/user` the cookie is there. Once I've given access, it works fine; just the initial allow. What is happening?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the "isSameSite" variable to the "Lax" value

```
const options = {
    connections: {
        state: {
            isSameSite: 'Lax'
        }
    }
};

const server = new Server(options);
```